# What is a good ratio of Activity : Fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a simple App with a few views. Theres the main view which is first loaded and displays the information, then from there I call the other view depending on what they click.

Would it be wise to have one activity calling all the other fragments? Or should I have multiple activities for a few fragments? What is a good ratio of activity : fragment?

Comment: `1:0`: http://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html.

Comment: @NiekHaarman yes that is one point of view I guess...but it isn't that common i don't think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your design, there are no hard and fast rules.

A typical design is to have one "navigation" fragment and one "content" fragment for an app.  The way, you can have navigation persisted on the left and load content as you would an activity in the right hand.

Comment: And those 2 fragments would be in one activity for the duration of the app's lifetime?

Comment: @fredjones the navigation activity would likely have a longer lifetime, whereas the content only lasts until the nav activity switches it out.  This is very common for tablets, and somewhat common these days for responsive UIs on phones.

Answer (score 0):

As you might know, there's a various set of Android devices with different screen sizes and densities. So it really depends on the how you design your application.

For instance, you can choose to have one parent activity for your handset layout, containing just one fragment (1:1), and then define a layout for tablet devices with a parent activity containing one or more fragments (1:x), because you have a bigger screen to show content.